# Read json file in jsr223 sampler in jmeter and extract data

Tags: json, parsing, jmeter, jsr223

```js
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath

def idCSV = new File('id.csv')
def index = [fileOne.json, fileTwo.json]

def jsonString

index.each { file ->
 jsonString = ________

 def ids = JsonPath.read(jsonString, '$..id')

 ids.each { id ->
  idCSV << id << newLine
 }
}
```

How to fill the jsonString = ____, so that I can json file into string and parse the string to extract ids and some information from the json string.
And I don't to do it in http request-> GET-> file format.
Previously i have extraced jsonString from http response and it worked well now I want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html):

```
def jsonString = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new File("json.txt").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you're looking for [File.getText()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#getText()) function

```
jsonString = file.text
```

---

I have no full vision why do you need to store the values from JSON in a CSV file, however there is an alternative way of achieving this which doesn't require scripting as your approach will work with 1 concurrent thread only, if you will add more users attempting writing into the same file - you'll run into a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) :

- You can read the files from the folder into JMeter Variables via [Directory Listing Config](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/directory-listing/DirectoryListing.md)
- The file can be read using [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler

  [image]
- The values cane be fetched using [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor), they will be automatically stored into JMeter Variables so you will able to use them later on
- If you need the values to be present in the file (although I wouldn't recommend this approach cause it will cause massive disk IO and potentially can run your test) you can go for the [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)